# Python : How to remove rows which has nan values for dict inside list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, dictionary

Have a dict in list with values:

a:

```
[{'name': 'toom D',
  'status_ref': True,
  'date_status_ref': Timestamp('2018-12-17 09:29:58.864000'),
  'expiry': None,
  'renew': nan},
 {'name': 'russ arnold',
  'status_ref': True,
  'date_status_ref': Timestamp('2018-12-17 09:29:58.864000'),
  'expiry': None,
  'renew': nan},
 {'name': 'cart wright',
  'status_ref': True,
  'date_status_ref': Timestamp('2018-12-17 09:29:58.864000'),
  'expiry': 'no',
  'renew': 'yes'}]
```

How to remove whole rows for records having nan , None , NaN values in  list(dict)

expected_output:

b:

```
[{'name': 'toom D',
'status_ref': True,
'date_status_ref': Timestamp('2018-12-17 09:29:58.864000')
},
{'name': 'russ arnold',
'status_ref': True,
'date_status_ref': Timestamp('2018-12-17 09:29:58.864000')
},
{'name': 'cart wright',
'status_ref': True,
'date_status_ref': Timestamp('2018-12-17 09:29:58.864000'),
'expiry': 'no',
'renew': 'yes'}]
```

Comment: NaN isn't a thing in Python.

Comment: @KenKinder I'm guessing there's a `from math import nan` omitted.

Comment: @MarioIshac, oooh, that could be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `nan` is `math.nan`, you can do this:

```
for sub_a in a:
    for key, val in sub_a.copy().items():
        try:
            if val is None or math.isnan(val):
                del sub_a[key]
        except TypeError:
            continue
```

The above will mutate the original `a`. If you want a separate `dict` `b` as the output, you can do `b = a.copy()` and replace `a` with `b` in the outer `for`.

The reason I wrapped `math.isnan` in a `try / except` is because not all values in your `dict`s are real numbers, some are strings. If the `TypeError` is thrown, we know that the value couldn't possibly be `nan`.

The resulting `dict` is:

```
[{'name': 'toom D',
  'status_ref': True,
  'date_status_ref': Timestamp('2018-12-17 09:29:58.864000')},
 {'name': 'russ arnold',
  'status_ref': True,
  'date_status_ref': Timestamp('2018-12-17 09:29:58.864000')},
 {'name': 'cart wright',
  'status_ref': True,
  'date_status_ref': Timestamp('2018-12-17 09:29:58.864000'),
  'expiry': 'no',
  'renew': 'yes'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through key/values of your dicts and filter them. like this:

```
a = [{'name': 'toom D',
    'status_ref': True,
    'date_status_ref': Timestamp('2018-12-17 09:29:58.864000'),
    'expiry': None,
    'renew': nan},
    {'name': 'russ arnold',
    'status_ref': True,
    'date_status_ref': Timestamp('2018-12-17 09:29:58.864000'),
    'expiry': None,
    'renew': nan},
    {'name': 'cart wright',
    'status_ref': True,
    'date_status_ref': Timestamp('2018-12-17 09:29:58.864000'),
    'expiry': 'no',
    'renew': 'yes'}]

def filter_dict(d):
    new_dict = dict()
    for (key, value) in d.items():
        if not (value is None or np.isnan(value)):
            new_dict[key] = value
    return new_dict

b = [filter_dict(d) for d in a]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution but you can try.

```
a = [{'name': 'toom D',
  'status_ref': True,
  'date_status_ref': 'a',
  'expiry': None,
  'renew': nan},
 {'name': 'russ arnold',
  'status_ref': True,
  'date_status_ref': 'b',
  'expiry': None,
  'renew': nan},
 {'name': 'cart wright',
  'status_ref': True,
  'date_status_ref': 'c',
  'expiry': 'no',
  'renew': 'yes'}]
```

---

```
for d in a:
    for k,v in d.copy().items():
        if (str(v) in ['None', 'NaN', 'nan']):
            d.pop(k)
```

---

**a:**

```
[{'name': 'toom D', 'status_ref': True, 'date_status_ref': 'a'},
 {'name': 'russ arnold', 'status_ref': True, 'date_status_ref': 'b'},
 {'name': 'cart wright',
  'status_ref': True,
  'date_status_ref': 'c',
  'expiry': 'no',
  'renew': 'yes'}]
```